# Get Date and Time of Specific Event Viewer Source

Tags: powershell

Attempting to get the Date and Time of Source Winlogon from EventViewer for timing purposes and this is what I currently have. I'm not the best at Powershell scripting but hopefully I was close enough to it's a simple fix. Please help! I've also referenced [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-winevent?view=powershell-6), but it didn't help to my prevail.

```
$LogSettingsEvent = "Winlogin"
$refDate = (Get-Date).Adddays(0)

Get-WinEvent $LogSettingsEvent -InformationAction | Where-Object 
{$_.LastWriteTime -gt $refDate}
```

Comment: 1st your refDate will hold the actual datetime, so it's unlikely to get much data. 2nd `-InformationAction` requires one of `[Continue | Ignore | Inquire | SilentlyContinue | Stop | Suspend]` 3rd  change your `Where-Object` to filter for TimeCreated ***not*** LastWriteTime.

Comment: Get-EventLog system | where {$_.InstanceId -eq 7001 -and $_.TimeWritten -gt (Get-Date).Adddays(-10)}

Comment: @f6a4 thanks! Exactly what I was aiming for and I didn't even think to use the ID, clever bud that answered my question! (You should post it as an answer)

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found to filter event logs is using `-FilterHastable'

Example (5 days of logs):

```
$LogSettingsEvent = "WinLogs"

[hashtable]$filter =@{}

$filter.Add('LogName', $LogSettingsEvent)

#add start time (5 days ago)
$start = (Get-Date).AddDays(-5)
#must have an endtime with start time (make it today)
$end = Get-Date

#Get the logs:
$systemLogs = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $filter

#display it
$systemLogs
```